# Running Macro in Notepad++ from Commandline

Tags: shell, macros, notepad++

Is it possible to run a Macro which i record in Notepad++ from the Commandline? Say i record a Macro to search and replace, which i can run in Np++ for the whole text file, i would like to do this kind of Job in a Shell file, is this possible? I couldnt find anything about this in the [Documentation](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/command-line).

If not possible can anybody recommend alternative easy to use porgrams for this kind of Job?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen any documentation on doing this in Np++, but I am pretty sure you can do it in UltraEdit. This is not a free product, though.